# std::vector constructor - why int and not int*?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I know that the following code can build a stl vector from an array:

```
  // the iterator constructor can also be used to construct from arrays:
  int myints[] = {16,2,77,29};
  std::vector<int> fifth (myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int) );
```

(source: [cppreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/))

the constructor used should be

```
template <class InputIterator>
         vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

if *< class InputIterator >* is *< int >* in the above example, why isn't the *InputIterator first* an integer pointer? The array name "myints" decays into a pointer to the first element because it's equivalent to &myints[0]

I thought a correct version would be

```
template <class InputIterator>
         vector (InputIterator *first, InputIterator *last,
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

Comment: `InputIterator` is `int*` in your case.

Comment: Iterators are not pointers. Pointers may model the iterator concept, but the other way around is not guaranteed by any means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is declared something like this:

```
template <class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
class Vector
{
  // ...
  typedef Allocator allocator_type;

  template <class InputIterator>
  vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
         const allocator_type& = alocator_type());

  // ...
};
```

Note that both the class itself and the constructor have template paremeters. When you create your `std::vector<int>`, the `int` template argument is for the class template paremeter `T`, determining the types of elements of the vector, not for the constructor's `InputIterator`.

You are allowing `InputIterator` to be deduced by the compiler (in fact, a constructor's template parameters must be deduced). Your are passing `myints` as the first argument to the function which is going to deduce `InputIterator`. Since `myints` decays to an `int*` to the first element of your array, as you say, then `InputIterator` will be deduced to be an `int*` and you get the following instantiation of the constructor:

```
vector (int* first, int* last,
        const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

`InputIterator` is not deduced to be `int`. It's deduced to be the full type that you pass as the first argument (and the second argument must match, of course).

This makes sense because an `int` is not a valid Input Iterator. Whatever `InputIterator` is deduced as must meet the requirements of an Input Iterator. An `int*` however, is valid.

Comment: Just two comments: for the type deduction to work, both `first` and `last` must deduce to the same type. (They do, both are `int*`.  But it's worth pointing out.)  And second, _if_ you write something like `std::vector<int> v( 10, 42 );`, it's also this constructor which gets chosen.  There is special language in the standard which says that if `InputIterator` is deduced to an integral type (here `int`), then the constructor must behave as if the first argument had type `size_t`, and not `int`.

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing the templated type of the vector (`int` in your case) with the templated type of the constructor's parameter. The constructor for `std::vector<T>` takes a first parameter of type `InputIterator`-yielding-`T`.

That is - `<class InputIterator>` is not `int`; it's an iterator that dereferences to `int`; such as `int*`

Answer (score 1):

This is because Iterators are not always pointers. Or put the other way: most Iterators are *not* pointers and therefore the signature you propose would not apply to them.

So in your case, `InputIterator` is `int*` which is perfectly understandable, since the concept of iterators initially was invented as a broader notion of "pointer range".

Answer (score 0):

`<class InputIterator>` cannot be `<int>` because you cannot dereference (apply `operator*()`) an `int`.

Comment: His point was then that the signature sues `InputIterator*`, which can be dereferenced.